# arbitrary nested for-loops with varying range (python)

Tags: python, recursion

I am studying a pattern that ended up having a fractal nature.  I wrote a function that handles the case when n=4.  It looks something like this:

```
    def enumerate_pattern(vector, n):
        path_len = len(vector)
        output = []
        for x in range(path_len-(n-1)):
            s1 = shifter(vector, 0, x)
            for y in range(path_len-(x+(n-1))):
                s2 = shifter(s1, x+1, y)
                for z in range(path_len-(x+y+(n-1))):
                    s3 = shifter(s2, x+y+2, z)
                    for w in range(path_len-(x+y+z+(n-1))):
                        s4 = shifter(s3, x+y+z+3, w)
                        some_function(s4) #which fills output
        return output
```

I'm trying to generalize it for any n but am having a hard time.  There is a pattern, but it is a little complicated. I found a recursive solution on this website for fixed range length and was trying to adapt it to my case.

```
def loop_rec(y, n):
    if n >= 1:
        for x in range(y):
            loop_rec(y, n - 1)
    else:
       whatever()
```

In my case, the whatever() would correspond to some_function(s4), I think.  But I don't know how to make the range change with each level. The For loop for ith level looks like this:

```
for L_i in range(path_len - (L_1+L_2+L_3+...+L_(i-1)+(n-1))):
   s_i = shifter(s_(i-1), L_1+L_2+L_3+...+L_(i-1)+(i-1), L_i)
```

Comment: can you provide a small concrete output and the expected output? trying to interpret your intention thru code is difficult, especially when it's not functioning to spec.

Comment: check my post below.  I edited it a little.

Comment: That's not a concrete input/output. Anyway, I highly suggest you replace `whatever` or `somefunction` with `yield`. This gives complete control to the caller, rather than tangling a side effect with your recursion logic.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: That's a concrete input but there is no concrete output. When I try to run the script, I see `NameError: name 'deepcopy' is not defined`. What is the expected output?

Comment: oh, forgot the import.   now it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can carry the varying part as a parameter.

```
def loop_rec(y, n, to_subtract=0):

    if n >= 1:
        for i in range(y - (to_subtract + (n - 1))):
            loop_rec(y, n - 1, to_subtract + i)
    else:
        whatever()
```

Comment: This may work, but I can't make sense of it.  I guess the main problem is, I don't have a good way to unpack these recursive functions.  I tried counting the number of times whatever() is called for a given y and n.  For example, loop_rec(4,3) calls whatever() 14 times.  In the example I gave above, path_len should be 24, which ends up calling some_function 10626 times.  I can't even get loop_rec to call whatever() that many times.  Closest I got was loop_rec(21,4) which calls whatever() 10350 times.  Maybe I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.  The important feature was given already by Joonyoung:  you have to carry the For index as an additional argument in the recursive function.  The reason the function calls didn't match is because, in my case, the n-1 part subtracted off of the range each round needs to stay the same.  That's why I was getting higher function calls to some_function().  I solved this by bundling that number with the initial vec length.

Here's what I came up with.  I used two functions.  One sets the initial conditions.  The other generates the arbitrary number of For loops with variable range.  I also included the shifter function and a print statement so you can see the pattern.

```
from copy import deepcopy

#shifts given element and all later elements over by some amount
def shifter(sequence, given_position, shift):
    sl_copy = deepcopy(sequence)
    sl_stored = deepcopy(sequence)
    for position in range(given_position,len(sl_copy)-shift):
        sl_copy[position+shift] = sl_stored[position]
    for element in range(given_position, len(sl_copy)-shift):
        if element < given_position + shift:
            sl_copy[element] = 0     
    return sl_copy

#recursive function to generate arbirary number of For loops
def enum_st_rec(states, shifts, base_vec, path_len, n, adjust=0, 
            counter=0):
    if n > 0:
        for i in range(path_len - adjust):
            shifts[counter+1] = shifter(shifts[counter], 
                                             adjust+counter, i)
            enum_st_rec(states, shifts, base_vec, path_len, n-1, 
                         adjust+i, counter+1)
    else:
        print(shifts[counter])
        stack = [[],[]]
        for i in range(len(base_vec)):
            if (shifts[counter][i] != 0 or base_vec[i] != 0):
                stack[0].append(shifts[counter][i])
                stack[1].append(base_vec[i])                             
        if stack not in states:
            states.append(stack)
    return states

#uses shifter function, enum_st_rec    
def enumerate_states(vec, base_vec, n):
    path_len = len(vec) - (n-1)
    states = []
    shifts = list(range(0,n+1))
    shifts[0] = list(vec)
    
    enum_st_rec(states, shifts, base_vec, path_len, n)
    
    return states

#example
vec = [1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
base_vec = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0]

output = enumerate_states(vec, base_vec, 3)

print(output)
```